# DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.Document

Tags: xpath, java

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) builder.parse("/home/danpetruk/strings.xml");
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.Document
```

Как исправить? [Следовал по](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-javaxpathapi/#listing3)

Comment: Нарооод! Проблема не решена, я в этой теме вообще не разбираюсь, так что нужна помощь...

Comment: а ошибки читать  умеешь?

Comment: Причину  ошибки понимаю - 2 разных типа. Но это не помогло мне исправить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse("/home/danpetruk/strings.xml");
```